# update hosts file on boot

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I'm trying to fix a problem where sudo takes a few seconds if the hostname is not in `/etc/hosts`.

this works from CLI:

```
sed -i "s/ubuntu-template/$HOSTNAME/g" /etc/hosts
```

but if I save it to a file `/etc/init.d/fixhostnames.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/ubuntu-template/$HOSTNAME/g" /etc/hosts
```

It doesn't do anything on boot. The file is +x and same permissions as other files in init.d.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? The new standard is `systemd`, which you can easily write a unit file for.

Comment: thanks for the tip j-money.

Here's what worked:

fixhostsfile.sh

`#!/bin/sh
hostnm=$(hostname)
sed -i 's/ubuntu-template/'"$hostnm"'/g' /etc/hosts`

and /etc/systemd/system/fixhostsfile.service

`[Unit]
Description=Fix etc/hosts

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/user/fixhostsfile.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`


Don't forget to systemctl enable fixhostsfile

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked.

In `fixhostsfile.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh 
hostnm=$(hostname) 
sed -i 's/ubuntu-template/'"$hostnm"'/g' /etc/hosts
```

And in `/etc/systemd/system/fixhostsfile.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix etc/hosts

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/user/fixhostsfile.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Don't forget to run:

```bsh
systemctl enable fixhostsfile
```